# What is the difference between "Notification" and "Attention" in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-source, android-notifications

I am learning about android source code and have studied about `LightsService` framework.

I know that those coding are different according to device. But I am getting confusion, while seeing the following code.

```
static int set_light_leds(struct light_state_t const *state, int type)
{
        struct an30259a_pr_control led;

        memset(&led, 0, sizeof(led));

        switch (state->flashMode) {
        case LIGHT_FLASH_NONE:
                led.state = LED_LIGHT_OFF;
                break;
        case LIGHT_FLASH_TIMED:
        case LIGHT_FLASH_HARDWARE:
                led.state = LED_LIGHT_SLOPE;
                led.color = state->color & 0x00ffffff;
                // tweak to eliminate purplish tint from white color
                if (led.color == 0x00ffffff)
                    led.color = 0x80ff80;
                // scale slope times based on flashOnMS
                led.time_slope_up_1 = (SLOPE_UP_1 * state->flashOnMS) / 1000;
                led.time_slope_up_2 = (SLOPE_UP_2 * state->flashOnMS) / 1000;
                led.time_slope_down_1 = (SLOPE_DOWN_1 * state->flashOnMS) / 1000;
                led.time_slope_down_2 = (SLOPE_DOWN_2 * state->flashOnMS) / 1000;
                led.mid_brightness = MID_BRIGHTNESS;
                led.time_off = state->flashOffMS;
                break;
        default:
                return -EINVAL;
        }

        return write_leds(&led);
}

static int set_light_leds_notifications(struct light_device_t *dev,
                        struct light_state_t const *state)
{
        return set_light_leds(state, 0);
}

static int set_light_leds_attention(struct light_device_t *dev,
                        struct light_state_t const *state)
{
        return set_light_leds(state, 1);
}
```

My first question is:

`set_light_leds_notifications()` and `set_light_leds_attention()` are using different second parameter, while calling `set_light_leds()` function.

But set_light_leds() function didn't use int type at all in their definition.

Then,

- What is the difference between them?
- What is the purpose of calling them separately?

My second question is:

- What is general different between Notification and attention in
  android application?

I know that both are used for notifying the user about information. But i want to learn more details about those difference and specifically in which situation attention is more important than notification.

Answer (score 1):

In Lights.h:

```
#define LIGHT_ID_BACKLIGHT          "backlight"
#define LIGHT_ID_KEYBOARD           "keyboard"
#define LIGHT_ID_BUTTONS            "buttons"
#define LIGHT_ID_BATTERY            "battery"
#define LIGHT_ID_NOTIFICATIONS      "notifications"
#define LIGHT_ID_ATTENTION          "attention"
```

The comment says

> These light IDs correspond to logical lights, not physical. So for
>   example, if your INDICATOR light is in line with your BUTTONS, it
>   might make sense to also light the INDICATOR light to a reasonable
>   color when the BUTTONS are lit.

And

```
#define LIGHT_ID_BLUETOOTH          "bluetooth"
#define LIGHT_ID_WIFI               "wifi"
```

So there might be some real light, for example, some Android pads have wifi lights, bluetooth lights. And there are also some logical lights, the Android designer design these logical lights such that different events can result different lighting effects.

In your code, the `set_light_leds_notifications` and the `set_light_leds_attention` are actually same because the `set_light_leds` doesn't differentiate them. It indicate that the device currently doesn't want to show different lights between notifications and attentions. But there might be some other devices who care.

The lights service in Android will get different implementations in different devices.

```
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_BACKLIGHT]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_BACKLIGHT);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_KEYBOARD]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_KEYBOARD);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_BUTTONS]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_BUTTONS);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_BATTERY]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_BATTERY);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_NOTIFICATIONS]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_NOTIFICATIONS);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_ATTENTION]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_ATTENTION);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_BLUETOOTH]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_BLUETOOTH);
    devices->lights[LIGHT_INDEX_WIFI]
            = get_device(module, LIGHT_ID_WIFI);
```

And I think I don't need to further explain this because you "know that those coding are different according to device."

For you second question: What is general different between Notification and attention in android application?

No Big difference. I don't think there is an entity named attention in NotificationManager. After checking the source, I found out that the attention light will be enabled when the FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS flag is set in a notification.

```
if ((n.notification.flags & Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS) != 0) {
    mAttentionLight.pulse();
}
```

So I think you can use the flags variable in Notification to differentiate attention and notification. In some devices, there might be no notification light, so there won't be any light flashing when there is a non-urgent notification. But there might be an attention light, so if your application has an important notification to notify the user, set the FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS on, and the attention light will be turned on.